# How to print an array of defined constants?

Tags: php, arrays, constants

I think that I have an easy questions, but I'm unable to find what I'm looking wrong!!

I've an array where there are some strings:

```
$tipus_membre = array("lider","colider","vetera","membre");
```

and this strings are defined:

```
define("LIDER","Leader");
define("COLIDER","Co-leader");
define("VETERA","Elder");
define("MEMBRE","Member");
```

I'm trying to print in a form but i'm unable to get it. With this first option i get only the name "lider", "colider"....:

```
<select name="cla_tipus" required>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($tipus_clan);$i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$tipus_membre[$i].'</option>';
}
?>
 </select>
```

and if i put:
      constant($tipus_clan[$i]);

I get nothing.

(Edited the $var)

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I believe `define` defaults to case-sensitive.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php ...

Comment: works fine if you change the array your looping to the correct var name which is `$tipus_membre`

Comment: This is what you want???

http://codepad.viper-7.com/84ql9F

Comment: Yes MixedVeg. Finally I've solved without changing the define(), using constant(strtoupper($tipus_membre[$i])).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the quick answers, finally the problem was where you said, in the case-sensitive.

The code now it works with a minor change and it's:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($tipus_clan);$i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.constant(strtoupper($tipus_membre[$i])).'</option>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    define("LIDER", "Leader");
    define("COLIDER", "Co-leader");
    define("VETERA", "Elder");
    define("MEMBRE", "Member");

    $tipus_membre = array(LIDER, COLIDER, VETERA, MEMBRE);

?>

<select name="cla_tipus" required>
    <?php

        foreach($tipus_membre as $k => $v)
            echo "<option value='" . $v . "'>" . $tipus_membre[$k] . "</option>";
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues with your code

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tipus_clan);$i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$tipus_clan[$i].'</option>';
}
```

You actually define $tipus_membre above, and then you use $tipus_clan in the for loop... which doesn't exist. Change the above to

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tipus_membre);$i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$tipus_membre[$i].'</option>';
}
```

Also, constant() is case sensitive; You'll want to define everything in $tipus_membre in uppercase (or convert them to uppercase when calling constant())for the defined constants to be grabbed, otherwise you'll get an undefined warning.

Comment: I believe you can also use `define("LIDER", "Leader", true)` to set the constant to be case-insensitive. :)

Comment: The call of the other $var was an copy error. Finally I've solved with: constant(strtoupper($tipus_membre[$i]))

Answer (score 1):

Constants are case-sensitive, maybe try making your array all uppercase, you can use

```
strtoupper()
```

function to capitalize

Comment: I added strtoupper() to the constant() function and now works well!